# SELECT data based on given pairs

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have little experience using SQL, and I am now using JDBC to connect to my database.
I am using sqlite, my schema looks as follows:

```
id1, id2, value1, value2
```

I want to extract rows based on a list of given pairs of id1 and id2.
I know Postgresql can do

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   ("id1", "id2") IN (('1', '2'), ('3', '4'));
```

But what about sqlite?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `IN`, you could use a `JOIN` using the two fields:

```
SELECT U.* 
FROM Table U
  INNER JOIN Table1 UT
    ON U.id1 = UT.id1
    AND U.id2 = UT.id2
```

Comment: Wrong database. And in this question, there is no second table that you could join with.

Comment: Removing the reference does not make the quoted text factually correct. Also see [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `OR`-condition:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (id1='1' and id2='2') OR
        (id1='3' and id2='4')
```

Comment: What if my list of id1 and id2 will be very long?

Comment: Then I'd actually introduce a table containing the pairs wanted, and then use a join.

Comment: Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (id1 = '1' AND id2= '2') OR (id1='3' AND id2='4');
```

Comment: What if my list would be very long?

Comment: @YIWENGONG Why dont you go for Join instead of IN, as i mentioned (here) [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427899/2118383]

Comment: @VigneshKumar Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a long list you can do this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (id1 in('1','11','111') and id2 in ('22','2','222')) OR
        (id1 in('333','33','3') and id2 in('444,'44','4')')
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.15.0, SQLite supports [row values](http://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  (id1, id2) IN (VALUES ('1', '2'), ('3', '4'));
```